# How to use invoke-command in powershell, to run a script on remote machine

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use `Invoke-Command` in PowerShell to run a script on a remote machine?

I have tried :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MyPC -Credential $mycreds -ScriptBlock {
    & "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\scripts\Script1.ps1"
}
```

which returns

```
script1.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

The scenario here is, I have some scripts on a remote folder, and I need to use `Invoke-Command` or some other ways to run the script on a remote machine.

Also, how  to write if I want to pass some parameters for `script1.ps1`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just tested using `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Server" -ScriptBlock {&"C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.ps1"}` and it worked fine for me - if you run that script manually does it work?

Comment: -filepath if the script is local not remote

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MyPC -Credential $mycreds -ScriptBlock {& "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\scripts\Script1.ps1"}
```

Try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MyPC -Credential $mycreds -FilePath C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\scripts\Script1.ps1
```

Comment: in this case, the filepath is a local file, not a path on remote machine. Am I right?

Comment: @davezhou Yes, you are correct. The file is local to the calling command and it's contents are executed on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid confusion with filepaths on local machines/remote machines; i always run stuff from smb-shares; you can enter UNC as filepath... eg:
-FilePath \server\Netscripts\script.ps1

Comment: Double hop problem if run remotely, unless it's in task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Or copy the script to remote machine.  The default remote directory is the documents directory.

```
$s = new-pssession mypc
copy-item script.ps1 c:\users\myuser\documents -tosession $s
invoke-command $s { .\script.ps1 }
```